# Can blender be used as non-linear editor easily?

Tags: animation, video

I am making a music video, greenscreening 1 person 14 times into a cathedral. How easy would it be to do this, with lots of moving shots from person to person, etc.(because I need to lip sync with an pre-recorded audio file).
Or would it be easier to render animation out of blender and track greenscreen footage in AE or Prpro?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you please give us a bit more information? What exactly do you mean with greenscreening a person "14 times" into a cathedral? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So there is 14 parts, each will be filmed separately (because it is the same person). And I will have to put each movie clip into the cathedral model. I have the subject in blender, and I would like to know if I can listen to audio for lip sync, and how to get the movie into the cathedral after I have taken out the bk. Thanks

Comment: The video editor in Blender (the VSE) does not have a Chroma Key effect. However you can set up another Blender Scene so that the video you want to "key" is sent through the compositor, which does have chroma keying ability.

Comment: Then this scene is used in the Video editing timeline instead of the original vision. You could also add the sound in that Compositing scene so that it is available in sync with the keyed media. Assuming that the media you are keying from doesn't change much but you could always animate the key settings to accomodate it.

Comment: OK, I know how to key in the compositing mode. What I'm wondering, is how easy this would be, doing this in blender versus exporting animation and working in AE and Prpro. Also, how can I footage from the compositing mode, into the 3d model mode? Thanks